# storing apps/games score in database like facebook

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

i was just playing helicopter game in facebook and i have realized that they are storing all scores in database and they are doing nice manupulation and utilisation for inviting other friends to that game. they will post on your profile and it will says users xyz has just crossed userabc challenge him again and it will show the highest score of entire facebook.

here is the link which i played at facebook

```
   https://apps.facebook.com/mg-copter
```

same game is also available in hundreds of websites but there they can not store any score to database. i have integrated helicopter game to my website and interested in storing all scores etc so that later i can do n number of manupulation of those scores just like facebook.if anyone is having any idea how can i store these scores in my php-mysql website it will be a great help..

same game at other site

```
   http://dagobah.net/flash/copter.swf
```

Comment: You just said that the other websites have this game but are unable to store any scores - so how  would you be able to?

Comment: If there is some method of extracting scores of users provided by the game then this might be possible... But essentially you are asking us to reverse engineer a flash game for you - that's not really how things work on [so]...

Comment: @Lix yes i said but in facebook they are storing score for the same game

Comment: @Lix i a not asking i just wanted to know how they are doing in facebook same way i want to store the score in my website